# Find a camera position by comparing points in 3d space

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have two images captured by a depth camera of the same object. I can mark some (say 5) points which are the same on the object and get their coordinates relative to camera position. Is it possible to find the camera position in the second image assuming 0,0,0 for the first image based on those coordinates?

Example:

**Image 1**
Camera position: 0,0,0
Camera angle (pitch, roll, heading): 0,0,0

point1: 21.3, 33.2, 44.1
point2: 28.3, 39.2, 41.5
point3: 23.4, 31.1, 53.4

**Image 2**
Camera position: ?
Camera angle: ?

point1: 23.4, 31.2, 44.7
...

I assume that based on the distances between the points and between points and the camera it would be possible to calculate. Can it be done with a simple script, e.g. in python, and without 3d libraries?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it can be done and it's pretty simple. You need three points. Are you comfortable with vector algebra? Dot-products and stuff?

Comment: I know what they are. I guess if I used python I could use numpy for it. Could you please provide some more details or a link? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what a vector basis is? And are the coordinates of those points Cartesian?

Answer (score 0):

If you know nothing about the camera, I don't think it is possible with two images.  In addition to an absolute scaling ambiguity (as in: if you shrank everything in the scene by a factor of 10, your camera images would be the same...), there is apparently a depth scaling ambiguity which no number of matching pairs can fix.  You can resolve this ambiguity by providing some number of absolute distance  values between sets of 3d points, or by some other method that provides the necessary additional length scales.  I found a [paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~hartley/Papers/cvpr92/final.pdf) on the subject, although it's not clear if the problem it solves is exactly the one you're looking for.

If you first *calibrate* the camera by measuring its geometric imaging characteristics, you can compute the relative camera positions of the two photos more easily (though absent additional information, you will still have the absolute scaling problem!).  If I recall correctly, you need at least 3 points, but the math is much simpler with 4.  One book on the subject (with sample chapters online) is [Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/); another is [The Geometry of Multiple Images](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262062208).

There is a library for doing this kind of thing in [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).  However, it doesn't have a function for doing exactly what you're looking for -- figuring out how to use it really requires some understanding of the math behind it, so you will need to read a book on the subject.